# How to change the extension of all files from a directory?

Tags: shell-script, directory, file-management

I am using Linux and I want to write a shell script that takes two directories and moves the second directory in the first one (so the second directory becomes a subdirectory of the first one) and all the files from the second directory become ".txt" extension. For exemple: `dir2` contains:

```
file1
file2
dir3
file3.jmp
```

After running `./shell_scrip dir1 dir2`, I want `dir1` to **contain** `dir2` and `dir2` would look like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
dir3
file3.txt
```

I tried to change the extensions but I got this error:

```
mv: cannot stat `file1`: No such file or directory
```

using the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in $2/*;
do
f=$(basename "$file")
mv "$f" "${f}.txt"
done
```

Comment: Put `echo` in front of the `mv` command to see where you're going wrong

Comment: "I want dir1 to contain dir2": what is `dir1` here? Is the script supposed to create a new directory and move the existing `dir2` into this new `dir1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not moving or referencing dir2.
Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "$2" "$1"  ||  exit               # Make $2 a subdirectory of $1
cd "$1/$(basename "$2")"  ||  exit   # Change directories for simplicity
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}.txt"            # Add or change the extension
done
```

Adding `|| exit` after the `mv` and `cd` commands will cause the script to exit if the command fails, which gives a little protection in case things aren't what you expect.

The expression `${f%.*}` is the same as `$f` if there's no period in the name.  Otherwise it removes the period (the last period) and everything after it.